# merge the json arrays without duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to merge this array without duplicate?

```
students1=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"}];

students2=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"},{studentId: "0004", name: "Jony", class: "1"}];

allStudents=$.merge(students1,students2);
```

Comment: did you google it? *How to remove duplicates from array?*

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `array#concat` both arrays and then use `array#reduce` to get the unique values from both arrays.

```js
const students1=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"}],
      students2=[{studentId: "0001", name: "Joe", class: "1"},{studentId: "0002", name: "john", class: "1"},{studentId: "0003", name: "Max", class: "1"},{studentId: "0004", name: "Jony", class: "1"}],
      allstudents = Object.values(students1.concat(students2).reduce((r,o) => {
        r[o.studentId] = o;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(allstudents);
```

Comment: Did you try to look for dupe?

Comment: Thank you friend it is helpful

Comment: @Hassan this will not work on IE 11 or lower due to `=>` expressions. Any code available for ES5 ?